# Is aviary free for commercial use?

Tags: licensing

I found a piece of software I would like to use but I am unsure if I can use it in a an app which generates money for me.

This is the app's legal terms but I am used to basic licences like apache or MIT: https://aviary.com/legal

Can I use this in my commercial app?

Comment: Wait, is aviary proprietary?

Comment: Also, Is your application open source?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about open source specifically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the software in question is not open source and there is no indication that the author's project is open source, thus making it off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

First, understand that this document is *not* anything like a free software license.  Just forget about all the freedoms to study, change, modify, improve and use the software that follows from free software licenses such as GPL, MIT and Apache.  This is not a software license, it is a developer contract that requires you to pay fees and also to pay Adobe/Aviary 70 % share of your "Adjusted Gross Revenue " from said app.

So it is certainly not "free" for commercial use. Not free as in "free beer", nor free as in "free speech".

However, you also ask this specific question:

> Can I use this is my commercial app?

I take this to mean:  Can I embed this software in my app, and then sell the app for money?

And yes - of course you can.  This is the basic idea behind this document: You embed the Aviary Photo Editor in your app, sell it (e.g. through Apple's, Google's and Microsoft's app stores) and give 70 % of your profit (after Apple et al has taken *their* cut) to Adobe/Aviary.

In addition to having to pay fees and share revenue, entering into this contractual relationship with Adobe/Aviary binds you to plenty of *other* restrictions. Everything that is not *explicitly* forbidden (such as reverse engineering) seems to require explicit approval by Adobe/Aviary.